# How to invoke ant for only one module while we have multiple module inside the SVN branch which has a main build.xml

Tags: jenkins, ant, build, hudson

There are a number of module in SVN branch and for build purpose we have one main build.xml which will trigger all the modules for build, we are using jenkins to invoke ant . Post build it will generate say five or six EAR ,now the problem is i want to trigger build only for one module which will have a new check in without changing the existing directory structure of branch in svn repo as jenkins will trigger build for all the module once it will find a check in in repo.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new jenkins job for required module only. Use your main build.xml as the input of the ant task but put the module name ( or related target ) as **Targets** in  jenkins task. If you have module specific build.xml then feed that file in this new Jenkins job.